# Why are these Character objects not retaining traits?

Tags: java, object

I'm writing a basic RPG for my AP Comp Sci class. For this question, the only two classes that matter are Character and Client. Client runs everything, and Character has lots of attributes a character would traditionally have.

**The problem:** I'm creating 2 different instances of a class called Character. However, when I try to print them out using the toString() method, only the most recently instantiated one prints.

**Attempted Solutions** I've tried writing the toString() method in other classes, and using Character as parameters, I've googled this issue, but haven't found anything similar. Also tried putting 'this.' in front of variables in the toString() method.

**The Code**

Client Class

```
import java.util.*;

public class Client{ //change to client

   public static void main(String[] args){

      Character NPC = new Character("Neil", 2, 20); //instance 1

      Character mainChar = new Character("Alfred", 3, 18);  //instance 2

      System.out.println(mainChar.toString());    //PROBLEM
      System.out.println(NPC.toString());         //PROBLEM

   }

}
```

Character Class

```
import java.util.*;

public class Character{
   public static String name; //name in gameplay, not in program
   public static int type; //1) tank, 2) range, 3) magic
   public static int hp; //health
   public static int age; //age
   public static int dmg; //avg. damage per attack
   public static int dmgMod; //+/- from dmg
   public static Item[] inventory = new Item[10]; //array of different things. Item is another class

   public Character(String name, int type, int age){
      int modify = new Random().nextInt(3);
      inventory[0] = new Weapon("Fists");
      this.name = name;
      this.type = type;
      this.age = age;

      this.hp = age * 15;
      this.dmg = 0; // ***
      this.dmgMod = 2 + (int)(this.age / 10) + modify;

   }
   //THIS is where the issue happens
   public String toString(){
      return "\nName: " + name + "\n" +
                         "Class: " + type + "\n" +
                         "Age: " + age + "\n" +
                         "HP: " + hp + "\n" +
                         "Damage: " + dmg + "\n" +
                         "Damage Modifier: " +  dmgMod;
   }
}
```

**What Prints Out**

Name: Alfred
Class: 3
Age: 18
HP: 270
Damage: 0
Damage Modifier: 5

Name: Alfred
Class: 3
Age: 18
HP: 270
Damage: 0
Damage Modifier: 5

**What Should Print Out**
Name: Alfred
Class: 3
Age: 18
HP: 270
Damage: [random]
Damage Modifier: [random]

Name: Neil
Class: 2
Age: 20
HP: 300
Damage: [random]
Damage Modifier: [random]

Thanks so much for the help, and I hope this isn't a stupid question. Also, as far as I could find, nothing similar to this question has been asked on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the use of the static keyword here means that any object of the "Character" class must have the same values in those attributes. because of this, when you create a new Character object, the previously created Character object has all of its attributes overwritten. get rid of all those static keywords and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize that static did all that . . . Time to go reread the documentation!